# Remove some semi colons in a data file

Tags: python, regex, notepad++, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

Hello I would like to remove some semi colons in my data file which is like this :

```
a;bfcse;g
g;qdq;d;u
q;g;sd;;o
c;dd;ea;b
w;;rz;z;m
```

And I would like to have this using a regex (because I try to select a column and to do a replace but it does not work the button in notepad++ was grey to replace in my selection) :

```
a;bfcse;g
g;qdqd;u
q;gsd;o
c;ddea;b
w;rzz;m
```

I thought to someting like a substring could be work but with notepad++ and sublimetext it is difficult...

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT : But I think it is very clear what I want to do is to remove the semi colons by nothing in this area :

```
  -------
a;|bfcse|;g
g;|qdq;d|;u
q;|g;sd;|;o
c;|dd;ea|;b
w;|;rz;z|;m
  -------
```

Comment: What is the logic here? Is the first example what you have and the second what you want? Can you add what you have tried and a clear example of what should be matched and replaced?

Comment: So  second line g;qd;d;u in your desired result is wrong?

Comment: No it is correct because I had `g;qdq;d;u` and then I had `g;qd;d;u` I removed in the area just above the semi colons

Comment: You removed the second q and not the semicolon?

Comment: Why `g;qdq;d;u` becomes `g;qd;d;u`? According to your request "remove the semi colons by nothing in this area", it should be `g;qdqd;u`

Comment: Exactly what I sasid @Toto.

Comment: looks like you want to retain first and last semicolon, and remove all the others?

Comment: Sorry indeed I removed the second q but it is an error I have just to remove semi colons

Comment: I'd give myself a useful comment +1 if I could ;>}  Debugged the question, did I.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.+?;|\G)(.*?);?(?=.*?;.+?$)`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # group 1
  ^             # beginning of line
  .+?           # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  ;             # a semicolon
 |              # OR
  \G            # restart from last match position
)               # end group 1
(.*?)           # group 2, 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
;?              # optional semicolon
(?=             # start lookahead, make sure we have after:
  .*?           # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  ;             # a semicolon
  .+?           # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  $             # end of line
)               # end of lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
$2          # content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
a;bfcse;g
g;qdqd;u
q;gsd;o
c;ddea;b
w;rzz;m
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new variable, and add everything that is not a semicolon, like so:

```
nosemicolons = ('')
somesemicolons = ('''  -------
a;|bfcse|;g
g;|qdq;d|;u
q;|g;sd;|;o
c;|dd;ea|;b
w;|;rz;z|;m
  -------''')
while len(somesemicolons) != 0:
    if somesemicolons[:1] != ';':
        nosemicolons = nosemicolons + somesemicolons[:1]
        somesemicolons = somesemicolons[1:]
    else:
        somesemicolons = somesemicolons[1:] #placeholder
print(nosemicolons)
```

Which outputs:

```
  -------
a|bfcse|g
g|qdqd|u
q|gsd|o
c|ddea|b
w|rzz|m
  -------
```

Sadly, it looks less like a table. You can change that so that it adds ' ' instead of nothing to the output (see placeholder). Hope that helps.